# Confusion about consistency of time series model parameter

Tags: time-series, estimation, consistency

Can someone clear this confusion. Lets say I have a time series model:

$$X_t \text{ follows Poisson}(\lambda_t)$$
$$\lambda_t=a*X_{t-1}+b*\lambda_{t-1}$$

Then I find estimators for $a$ and $b$ called: $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{b}$.

If the sample size increases:

1. I take for example x data for 10 days calculate $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{b}$
2. then I take x data for 50 days calculate $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{b}$
3. then I take x data for 100 days calculate $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{b}$

The mean of $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{b}$ should approach the true value of $a$ and $b$ to be consistent? Am I correct? Does it being a time series matter?

Also to calculate the means of $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{b}$, does the number of sample used matter? Like 100 different 10 days samples or 500 different 10 days samples.

I will get the samples using a computer simulation using the true values of $a$ and $b$.

Edited for context:
I will explain.

1. I will use a computer simulation using value a and b to generate 500 different 10 days long data. Then calculate 500 different $\hat{a}$s and $\hat{b}$s. Then get mean($\hat{a}$) and ($\hat{b}$).
2. I will use a computer simulation using value a and b to generate 500 different 50 days long data. Then calculate 500 different $\hat{a}$s and $\hat{b}$s. Then get mean($\hat{a}$) and ($\hat{b}$).
3. I will use a computer simulation using value a and b to generate 500 different 100 days long data. Then calculate 500 different $\hat{a}$s and $\hat{b}$s. Then get mean($\hat{a}$) and ($\hat{b}$).

Then get 3 differents means for ($\hat{a}$) and ($\hat{b}$) for 1),2) and 3).  Will mean($\hat{a}$) and mean($\hat{b}$) approach $a$ and $b$?.
And, thus will I be able to say that $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{b}$ are consistent estimators.

Comment: Hi: If you do  1,2 and 3, then it would be nice if the estimates approached their true values ( not sure what you mean by means ). But this will only true in the case where you have correctly specified the model and the model ( and the model parameters ) do not change over time. This is always a difficult problem with time series analysis because often, either the model or the parameters do not remain constant over time.This is why it is sometimes best to cut off the back of the data and add some to the front and then check how your parameter estimates change relative to their previous values.

Comment: @mlofton edited post for clarification

Comment: Consistency is a property describing what happens *in the limit* (as $n\to\infty$). You can't make any definitive statements by observing the approach for a set of finite samples. It's possible to define *inconsistent* estimators that seem to progress nicely, approaching the population parameter for a while (up to some large but finite $n$) and then no longer approaching it. So observing behavior where things "get closer with $n$" up to some finite sample size is not of itself sufficient; you'd need a stronger argument than just "Look! It keeps getting closer every larger sample size I check."

Comment: ... Such evidence is encouraging (certainly more so than *not* seeing it), but not dispositive.

Comment: @Thon: Given what you're doing, one would expect the means ( or even more strongly, the estimates themselves ) to approach their true values. But, as Glen_b said, you really $n = \infty$ in order to show that empirically. I would think that it should be possible to prove the consistency of the two estimators given the underlying DGP. I'm not sure what the approach would be but it seems like it should be possible.